# Can const value be changed using initialiser list?

Tags: c++, constants

I have initialized the const reference z and tried to reinitialize it using initializer list and the output I am getting is the changed value.
No errors no warnings.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Point {
    private:
    const int &z=9;

    public:
    Point (int &c):z(c){}

    int get_setz(){
        return z;
    }

};

int main()
{
    int m=3;
    Point p(m);
    cout << p.get_setz();
    return 0;
}

Output :
3
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with references or with const. An entry in an initializer list beats an in-class initializer. When you have both, the in-class initializer is ignored. This **has to be** a duplicate, but a brief search didn’t find one.

Answer (score 5):

> I have initialized the const reference z and tried to reinitialize

You tried, but you didn't. When a constructor member initialization list is used to initialize a member, any default member initializer is ignored. `z` never referred to a temporary with the value `9`. So the rules of C++ are still very much in play, you may not reseat a reference, and there was never even an attempt to do so.

And had you not initialized `z` with `c`, you'd have a dangling reference and code with undefined behavior on your hands. Because that `9` is not an object, it's a literal. References can only bind to objects, and so you'd have bound it to a temporary that would have gone out of scope once the initialization of your object was complete.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
One more thing I have to ask here is that when I am removing &z=9 to &z; and making the constructor to :


    Point (int &c){
            z=c;
        }

then why am I getting this error as '‘const int& Point::z’ should be initialized' ?
why is it that const member need to be initilised using initializer list?

Comment: @nihaldixit - Only an initialization list does initialization in a consturctor. Doing it in the body is *assignment* after initialization was done.